# Set int position to the line after a string is read

Tags: java

Edit: As some have asked, I will try to make it more clear. The user inserts a value, any value, into a text box. This is saved as the `result` int. The problem is finding the right line to insert the strings to for every choice the user might make.

I am trying to insert strings through a loop in a file and as it is right now, I'm using a static declaration of the location (line number) through an int. The problem is that if the number of iterations changes, the strings are not inserted in the right location.

In the code below, `result` represents the number of strings to be inserted, as written by the user in a text box.

```
for (int a = result; a >= 1; a--) {    
        Path path = Paths.get("ScalabilityModel.bbt");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        int position = 7; 
        String extraLine = "AttackNode" + a;   

        lines.add(position, extraLine);
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
```

I would like to change "int position = 7" to something like position = "begin attack nodes" + 1 (so that the string is inserted on the line below the line that contains the string I'm looking for.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: So, why You don't use `position=a+1;` ?

Comment: @Dred Because I don't know how to get the index/location of a, that's why I asked.

Comment: Ok, how position depends on lines were inputted by User? For example, If user inputs 7 strings, which position should be? and which if user inputs 2 strings. It is not clear your relation between position and string's count

Comment: @Dred exactly, if the user inputs 7, then 7 lines are inputted at that location. Yep it's exactly like that, which position should it be if the user selects 53 for example, or 17. Or anything else. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the comments in the question that user wants to add 2 lines (for example). If user adds '2' into input box.

Please mention in the comment if I am missing something.

One of the way to get that can be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Assuming the user input here
    int result = 2;
    for (int a = result; a >= 1; a--) {
        Path path = Paths.get("ScalabilityModel.bbt");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // Used CopyOnWriteArrayList to avoid ConcurrentModificationException
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> myList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(lines);

        // taking index to get the position of line when it matches the string
        int index = 0;
        for (String string : myList) {
            index = index + 1;
            if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("AttackNode")) {
                myList.add(index, "AttackNode" + a);
            }
        }
        Files.write(path, myList, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the reading of the file to outside the loop and created a list of the lines to add. Since I wasn't sure what string you want to match with I added a variable `searchString` for this, so just replace it or assign the right value to it.

```
Path path = Paths.get("ScalabilityModel.bbt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String searchString = "abc";

List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
  String extraLine = "AttackNode" + (result - i);
  newLines.add(extraLine);
}

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
  if (lines.get(i).contains(searchString)) { //Check here can be modified to equeals, startsWith etc depending on the search pattern
    if (i + 1 < lines.size()) {
      lines.addAll(i + 1, newLines);
    } else {
      lines.addAll(newLines);
    }
    break;
  } 
}
```